# Error Converting x86 asp.net project to x64

Tags: c#, asp.net, 64-bit

I've an ASP.Net 4.5 solution that compiles & runs when set to ANYCPU, but I've a method that needs more memory and this project is going to live in an x64 environment so I figured recompile and problem solved. Wrong. After a successful build, I get this error when attempting to debug the app:

```
Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Core' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

So far, I've double checked my Solution configuration properties and all of the project properties, everything is consistent at x64.

What else could be hindering the conversion? A 32bit only reference perhaps?

**I've published my app to a 64bit webserver with the target platform as ANYCPU. Private Memory Limit is roughly 6gbs. While running the memory intensive method (export to excel via the ClosedXML Library) memory used by the app peaks @ 2.7gbs and gets flushed, then raising the OutOfMemory Error. 
It seems the applciation is still running in 32bit mode?

***FIXED: I stopped throwing the OutOfMemory Exception by adding this to the post-event build options:

```
call "$(DevEnvDir)..\..\vc\vcvarsall.bat" x86
"$(DevEnvDir)..\..\vc\bin\EditBin.exe" "$(TargetPath)"  /LARGEADDRESSAWARE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AnyCPU means that your application will run as a 64-bit process on 64-bit IIS and as 32-bit process on 32-bit Cassini dev server. You won't be able to run application compiled for x64 on 32-bit Cassini.

Bottom line is: you're fine with AnyCPU target and you will get the benefits of x64 environment.

Comment: I realize how ignorant I sound here, but I"m learning as I go. is a 32 bit Cassini environment == IISExpress?

Comment: @JonBruce: no, Cassini is development server that ships with Visual Studio.